# visible tab width in sublime text 2

Tags: indentation, sublimetext2

I want to change the width of \t (tab) character. I don't mean tab_size in settings (I couldn't google anything else than this), I mean visual width of one tab character, to be equal to 4 spaces.

If I set "tab_size":4 and then convert file to tabs/spaces, four spaces get translated to one tab, or one tab to four spaces. Well that's nice. But actual visible width of tab character seems to be calculated as  (3 * tab_size * the size of space). That effectively triples visible indentation. I don't know where does the number 3 come from. I checked settings, checked plugins, tried to set different "tab width" in command palette, tried new files and new projets (in case there was some forgotten settings connected to old ones) but to no success.

I edit lot of files that have mixed indentation with tabs and spaces, even on the same line, so the indentation is broken in sublime and I have to manually fix it.. The result I want is, that when I do "convert to tabs" or "convert to spaces" (with tab_size: 4), the code simply doesn't move. 4 spaces should get translated to one tab of the same size like four spaces.

Comment: Is this for any particular file type? There are various packages you can install to tidy/indent messy files eg for XML, HTML, JSON, etc

Comment: I tryed json, .php, html, css and xml, tab is 3*tab_size spaces wide all the time. We solved the problem the hard way recently, we used another editor to rewrite all files to tab-only indent. But anyway, it would be nice to have some control over the tab-width. If you know some plugins that solve this, can you suggest some please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only think I found that changes that is font. Real tab width seems to be calculated as `tab_size` times width-of-m-character. So the only possible way seems to be to switch to a font, where space has same width as m character (monospace font for instance), to have size of tab with `tab_size=1` equal to one space-width. I really don't like monospace fonts, but yeah, they are almost a must for programming.

The reason why it seemed to be that space width was equal to 3*tab_size was because my font's space-width was about 1/3 of `m` character